# iam inserting an Opportunity record, but I need it to have HasOpportunityLineItem = true (HasOpportunityLineItem read only field)

Tags: apex, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, product

iam inserting an Opportunity record, but I need it to have HasOpportunityLineItem = true (HasOpportunityLineItem read only field)

present HasOpportunityLineItem = false but i need to HasOpportunityLineItem = true  this is my code please anybody help me

Read-only field that indicates whether the opportunity has associated line items. A value of true means that Opportunity line items have been created for the opportunity. An opportunity can have opportunity line items only if the opportunity has a price book. The opportunity line items must correspond to PricebookEntry objects that are listed in the opportunity Pricebook2. However, you can insert opportunity line items on an opportunity that does not have an associated Pricebook2. For the first opportunity line item that you insert on an opportunity without a Pricebook2, the API automatically sets the Pricebook2Id field, if the opportunity line item corresponds to a PricebookEntry in an active Pricebook2 that has a CurrencyIsoCode field that matches the CurrencyIsoCode field of the opportunity. If the Pricebook2 is not active or the CurrencyIsoCode fields do not match, then the API returns an error. You can’t update the Pricebook2Id or PricebookId fields if opportunity line items exist on the Opportunity. You must delete the line items before attempting to update the PricebookId field.

i follow The above rules

this is my code

```
Account acc=new Account();
acc.Name = 'TestAccountName';
acc.Industry = 'Automotive';
insert acc;

Opportunity opp=new Opportunity();
opp.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
opp.StageName = 'Identifying';
opp.Type = 'New Business';
opp.Description = 'test desc';
opp.CloseDate = system.today();
opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
opp.Amount = 222;

insert opp;

Product2 pt=new Product2();
pt.Name ='Test Product';
insert pt;



Pricebook2 pb=new Pricebook2();
pb.IsActive = true;
pb.Name = 'Test Pricebook';
insert pb;
```

Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

```
PricebookEntry pentry= new PricebookEntry();
pentry.Pricebook2Id = pricebookId;
pentry.Product2Id = pt.Id;
pentry.UnitPrice =  777;
pentry.IsActive = true;
insert pentry;    

OpportunityLineItem oitem=new OpportunityLineItem();

oitem.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
oitem.Product2Id = pt.Id;
oitem.Quantity = 2;
oitem.TotalPrice = 222;

insert oitem;
```

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest those options instead:

In case you don't use that field for any other reason, change his field-level security and mark as read-only on the page layout.

If you have only one profile to create the opportunity change the access of him to edit the field.

Set the field as editable and create a validation rule to opportunity object to validate whether someone try to change the value.